# Time an Android thread in a better way? (runs out of sync)

Tags: android

Hey I am currently designing an app where some code gets executed every 200ms. The thread I use for this looks like this (simplified):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
    {   public void run() 
        {
              handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
            switch (status){
    case 1: check(1);p2.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000); p1.setBackgroundColor(0xDDCC0000);  status = 2; break;
    case 2: check(2);p1.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000); p2.setBackgroundColor(0xAAAA0000);  status = 1; break;
            }
        }
    }; runnable.run();
```

check() contains some non-UI code lines.

The problem is, that the postDelayed-200-ms start, when the queue is fully executed and not at the beginning so all time that the system needs to execute the commands stacks and stacks all the time so these are actually ~210-230ms (depending on CPU load)

Then I tried to get the system date at the beginning of the thread and add 200ms to it but this results in some other, "heavier" errors.

I have no problem with more than 200ms delay, I just want to get it running stable.

I hope you understand my problem and can give some advice to me.

EDIT: I know got to know that the Handler runs acceptable (delay of 4ms on 200ms). The problem are the methods I am calling then. I will open a new question

Comment: try thread.sleep instead;

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this results is pretty much the same problem :/

Comment: looks like 200ms is making it difficult.

Comment: Yea, if it would be 600 or sth like that, no one would ever notice the delay

Answer (score 0):

If check() contains non-ui code lines then you should run those in a separate thread.

The bottom line is that the UI thread is *really busy, so, you can ask it to do something every 200ms but you aren't guaranteed any precision since the Device is doing its best to do all sorts of other things.    When you say "heavier problems" what do you mean exactly?

I would try to start a Thread and just Log every 200ms to see if the device is willing to accurately do *anything at the rate you wish.  If it does, then you can send messages to the UI thread to draw and if you find that its the drawing that is delayed, then perhaps you need to reduce your delay to give the UI thread time to finish drawing? (obviously this is also highly imprecise and will vary wildly from device to device).

Comment: Ok I now tried to exclude every UI-related code, and all this still runs extremely uneven >.<

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing it using [Timers](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29)? A basic implementation would look like

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}, 200, 200);
```

You can try using the alarm service as well. that should give you accurate (or at least consistent) results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this idea, I tried it in this way like you posted and it results in exactly the same. I will try with alarm service. If it worked, I'll mark as answer :)